# React Router dom and Google webcache content 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The scenario is a bit specific and tricky.
There's a client application built with ReactJS and react-router-dom for routing.
Routing is pretty basic like below.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route component={404} />
</Switch>
```

After google has indexed the site, and upon checking the webcache of the application, the 404 page was shown, no matter what URL of the website was accessed.

What I understood from the scenario, google webcache might append something to the URL, and since we are looking for `exact` URLs, it is going to error.

So I rearranged the routing structure

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  <Route path="/404" component={404} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
</Switch>
```

Now what happens is,

1. Home is the default component now
2. 404 page will not appear unless routed to 404

After the above change, google webcache is going to the default Homepage, for all the URLs.

Any way to tackle this problem?

sample webcache URL looks like below
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow&q=cache%3Adomain.com%2Fabout%2F

**UPDATE**

Tried with wildcard options too.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about*" component={About} />
  <Route path="/404" component={404} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
</Switch>
```

But still in Google webcache, `about-us` page is going to the homepage.

**UPDATED WITH EXAMPLE**
to illustrate issue with example, 
[NO match, 404](https://r1nt9.codesandbox.io/will-match&first_name=joe)

[Codesandbox example to illustrate the issue](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-no-match-404-r1nt9)

**UPDATE**

I wrote an article about Google Web cache and SEO, this might help you to understand that this issue may not be that relevant anymore.
[Link to Medium article](https://medium.com/@georgejustin22/why-google-web-cache-is-not-as-important-for-seo-as-you-think-ce4026c1eb6d)

Comment: Keep the `exact` for `<Route path="/" component={Home}/>`

Comment: in that case, if any extra params appended to the URL, it'll be 404. Wouldn't it? Just like the first scenario

Comment: You can use "exact={true}" property in route of react router to exact routing, it handle your redirection to "/" when the url is /about-us, by insert  "<Route component={404} />" route for catching the 404.

Comment: @behnamshateri may be I wasn't clear enough. `exact` will look for an exact match. Any dynamic append to the URL will go to 404. I have added codesandbox module to elaborate the issue.

Comment: @JustinGeorge: Have you figured out this problem? if so then can you guide me how you fixed this issue? I'm running in the same issue. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @DawoodButt not really. After hours of researching, I realized that Google cache is not very important. The main culrpit here could be the URL. In the Google webcache URL, they encode and append couple of things. If your application can parse those without any errors, I guess it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your code and your explanation you have 3 route:

1) `\` as your root of your project

2) `old-match` that you want to redirect to will-match

3) `will-match` that want to show `WillMatch` component

and unknown route must be render `NoMatch` component.
for this purpose its better to implement this approach in your `example.js` in `codesandbox` that you said above for your routes to handle redirect and 404 component:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route exact={true} path='/old-match' render={() => { return <Redirect to="/will-match" />; }} />
    <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May be I didn't do a good job in explaining the problem, your solution is not the on I'm looking for. Google webcache modifies the URL with URL encoding and all. then, none of the sub url will work with client side routing.

Comment: @justin-george did u find any solution to this????

Comment: No @ANOOPNAYAK google cache wasn't very crucial to our website

Comment: @JustinGeorge I'm also facing the same error so can you tell me is any method works for you?